# why i get infinity ? can it solved?

Tags: java, infinity

i have code like this, i try to get number from henon formula

```
public class henon 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {         
        double a = 0.3;
        double b = 1.4;    
        double k[] = new double[1026];
        k[0] = 0.01;
        k[1] = 0.02;              

        for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
        {                       
            k[i+2] = 1 - (a * Math.pow(k[i+1], 2) + b * k[i]);          
            System.out.println( "nilai ke" + i +" adalah " + k[i]);
        }
    }               
}
```

how i can get infinity valuew in 24, 25 ...how to solve it?

Comment: Please, take a breath and explain your issue more clearly.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? your k[] has `0.01,0.02,0.98588....` ..?

Comment: i try to get number from henon formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is better for your requirement.

double and float are not useful for accurate results as Joshua bloch said in Effective Java.

```
BigDecimal k[] = new BigDecimal[1026];
        k[0] = new BigDecimal(0.01);
        k[1] = new BigDecimal(0.02);  
        for (int i = 2; i < k.length; i++) {
            k[i]=new BigDecimal(0.0);
        }
```

if you want double value of Bigdecimal ,you can use doubleValue() method.

Comment: bigdecimal is new for me ... i try to change double with bigdecimal, but i get error in this double a = 0.3;
        double b = 1.4;

Comment: u may explain with good example i didnt get it,u can see my edited answer

Comment: im already succes to do this but 1 problem bigdecimal can't use to math.pow in my code there is pow process can you help me sir ?

Comment: Bigdecimal has got pow() method u can try it

Answer (score 0):

You're getting "infinite" values because your calculations are going beyond the range of a `double` data type.

If you need more range, you'll have to resort to something like a bignum library, such as [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: @Marko, you're right of course, I mistakenly thought this was C hence my reference to MPIR. Changed to BigDecimal since it's more relevant to Java.

Comment: Your proposal wasn't all wrong because people do crave the C library for speed. BigDecimal is crap in that category, but it's much easier to start with.

Comment: can you give me donwload link for GMP

Comment: MPIR is at http://www.mpir.org/ and GMP is at http://gmplib.org/ - I've always gotten a better response to problems and suggestions from MPIR (a fork of GMP) so that's my preference.